# selecting span value inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have

```
    <div id="1">
    <span id="name">Josh</span>
    <div id="quote">Run</div>
    </div>

    <div id="2">
    <span id="name">Mark</span>
    <div id="quote">Run</div>
    </div>
```

How would I select the name between the span tags from the first div?

```
$("#quote").click(function(){

    var name = $('#name').html();

});
```

Comment: You can't have any duplicate tags (`id="name"`) - all IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `id`'s have to be unique in an html document. So,ideally, you need to change those id's within the div to a `class`. Secondly, `id`'s cannot begin with a numeric, so you need to change your div id's to start with a letter or underscore.

With that in mind, given this structure:

```
<div id="one">
    <span class="name">Josh</span>
    <div class="quote">Run</div>
</div>

<div id="two">
    <span class="name">Mark</span>
    <div class="quote">Run</div>
</div>
```

you would be looking for:

```
$("#quote").click(function(){

    var name = $('#one .name').html();

});
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that while some browsers allow you to use numerical IDs, the W3C spec specifically says you shouldn't and you therefore cannot count on *all* browsers allowing it.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to determine which <div class="quote">Run</div> is clicked based on your example? For example if the quote div was clicked, would I be able to capture the name span? I assume it's possible since the parent divs are unique.

Comment: @domino Just use `this` and a little DOM traversal inside your `click` handler: `var name = $(this).parent().find('span.name').text();`

Answer (score 1):

`id`'s should be unique across a page. You should change the `name` and `quote` id's to a class, which do not have to be unique.

```
<div id="1">
    <span class="name">Josh</span>
    <div class="quote">Run</div>
</div>

<div id="2">
    <span class="name">Mark</span>
    <div class="quote">Run</div>
</div>
```

You could then select via:

```
$('#1 .name')
```

You should also bare in mind that `id`'s should not start with a number (except in HTML5)

Answer (score 0):

Adding #1 before #name would select the first div

```
$("#quote").click(function(){
     var name = $('#1 #name').html();
});
```

Comment: please avoid having duplicate ids. Instead make them class

Answer (score 0):

```
 var name = $("#1 span").html()
```

or

```
var name = $('#1 #name').html();
```

Comment: What is the problem here ?? :-O

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

```
$("#1 span").text();
```

You have some problems with your HTML though.  You should not have any duplicate IDs in your HTML, they must be unique.  ID shouldn't start with a number either.

You can view the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

you can select the first span tag content of your div #1 this way  as well :

```
var name = $("#1 span:first").html();
```